# How to code after successful unobtrusive remote validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have set up remote validation on a input control which accepts employee code. Remote validation checks if the code is valid. This works like a charm.

But, in the event of successful validation I would like to return more information for my web page (name, address, telephone number) which would be displayed on the page.

Can you give me the link or an example on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Do an ajax call to your controller/action from your client side upon successful remote validation. Use HTML DOM manipulation to show and hide the contents.

Comment: So, you're suggesting 2 ajax calls in total? One for validation and one for fetching data? Doesn't seem right.

Comment: The one for validation happens without any explicit call as the framework takes care of it. So only 1.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more detail or code?

From what i can gather you're wanting something like this in your controller:

```
public JsonResult EmployeeCodeValidate(string employeeCode)
{
    if(!Valid(employeeCode)) // however you are validating here
    {
        return Json(new { valid = false;});
    }

    EmployeeDetails details = GetEmployeeDetails(employeeCode);

    return Json(new { valid = true, details = details });
}

class EmployeeDetails
{
    string name { get; set; }
    string phoneNo { get; set }
    ...   
}
```

If this is the sort of thing you're meaning then the JavaScript would look like:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/Controller/EmployeeCodeValidate?employeeCode=" + code,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        ajaxSuccess(data);
    }
});

function ajaxSuccess(data){
    if(data.valid) {
        //add elements using data.details.name etc
    }
}
```